# How can I propagate CXX_STANDARD and related properties to dependent targets?

Tags: cmake, build, compiler-options, build-target

When you set a CMake target's property, you can make it `PUBLIC`, `INTERFACE` or `PUBLIC`. Yet - the CMake manual [page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) on the `CXX_STANDARD` property does not indicate the ability to specify one of these. Specifically, suppose I have:

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES 
        CXX_STANDARD 11
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
        CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)
```

Is it really unavailable? And if so, why?

(Note: This question applies just the same to C or any language which CMake supports this way.)

Comment: if you look at target properties list, there is no `INTERFACE_CXX_XXXX`
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#target-properties

Answer (score 3):

As @Mizux points out in a comment, it seems you can't - at the moment - make these `CXX_`-prefixed options propagate to dependent targets: Propagating properties are named `INTERFACE_` + the original property name - and there are no properties with prefix `INTERFACE_CXX_` in the [master list of target properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#target-properties) as of October 2020.

I don't know why this is the case.

However - one can obtain the effect of `INTERFACE` or `PUBLIC` on these properties, to some extent, by using the [`target_compile_features()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html) command (or is it a macro? I always get those mixed up), with one of the features: `cxx_std_98`, `cxx_std_11` etc. Thus, for example:

```
target_compile_features(mylib PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

but that's still not the exact `PUBLIC` equivalent of OP's command in the question: This doesn't prevent the availability of GNU extensions. So, it's a half-solution - and I don't like it anyway because the syntax in the question is nicer.